# How to update Java Calendar object close to current Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-8

I've a Calendar object which is set to 2 years ago. I want to update this calendar object close to the current time by adding hours but it shouldn't past the current time.

For example, original date is `June 24,2015- 11:20:52:200`

Current time is `Jul 14,2016- 14:08:30:100`

I want to get the timestamp as `Jul 14,2016-13:20:52:200`

The update should be propagated backwards in days if required as well. In case the original time is `June 24,2015 00:20:50:200`, and the current time is `June 27,2015 00:15:20:100`,  I need to get `June 26,2016 23:20:200`.

Is there a native method in Java 8 that gives this kind of functionality?

Comment: No, you have to write it.

Comment: So you want a new date-time as close as possible to, but not exceeding, the current date-time that has the past date-time’s time-of-day?

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The `java.util.Calendar` class is now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `LocalTime`

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day alone, without a date and without a time zone.

We can extract a `LocalTime` from both your past date-time and your current date-time and compare. If the past `LocalTime` is same or earlier than current one, we can stick with current date-time and adjust to the past time-of-day. If the past `LocalTime` is after the current `LocalTime`, then we must use yesterday’s date.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime pastZdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2015 , Month.June, 24 , 11 , 20 , 52 , 200_000_000 , zoneId );
ZonedDateTime nowZdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );

LocalTime pastTOD = pastZdt.toLocalTime();
LocalTime nowTOD = nowZdt.toLocalTime();

ZonedDateTime target = null;
if( pastTOD.isAfter( nowTOD ) ) {  // Use yesterday’s date.
    target = ZonedDateTime.of( nowZdt.toLocalDate().minusDays( 1 ) , pastTOD , zoneId );

} else {  // Else, the past time-of-day is same or ealier than today’s time-of-day, so use today's date.
    target = ZonedDateTime.of( nowZdt.toLocalDate() , pastTOD , zoneId );
}
```

**Beware:** That particular time-of-day may not be valid on this particular date because of anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Be sure to read the class documentation to understand the resulting behavior that adjusts to fix such a predicament. That behavior may or may not meet your needs (no perfect remedy is possible).

Caveat: Above code was never run. Use at your own risk. Please edit to fix if you discover flaws.